# Important Services Delegated to User Space

Tags: service, operating-system, kernel

I'm studying for an exam, and this was a sample question:

List important services that may be potentially implemented as kernel services but modern kernels choose to ignore, i.e., delegate to user space, following an Ostrich approach to system design. Explain the rationale for doing so for each of the services listed.

So these have to be services which are quite rare but expensive to function in kernel space? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like others to comment on this, but would udev be a good example of one of those services?